# Postgresql log to distant logstash server

Tags: postgresql, logging, syslog

I'm setting up a logs's collector. I have my application that send log using SyslogAppender (log4j) to my distant log server. I can also save all applications logs and postgresql database logs, using a curl command-line. My logs server is an ELK server (all in same cluster).

But now I want to send postgresql logs automatically, like I do with Appender and application logs. Is it possible to do this with *postgresql.conf* file? Or do I have to use a logstash forwarder? (if possible I like to avoid use of forwarder)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either log postgres to a file and have loggstash-forwarder send it to the central log server. This is secure as it requires the use of an ssl cert.

You can also output postgress to syslog and have rsyslog send the logs to your log server.

Postgres -> syslog  (postgresql.conf)

```
 log_destination = 'syslog'
 syslog_facility = 'local0'
 syslog_ident = 'postgres'
```

rsyslog -> logstash (/etc/rsyslog.conf)
The format is facility.loglevel @@server address:port    (@ for udp, @@ for tcp)

```
 local0.* @@db-private:5544
```

logstash input

```
 input{
   syslog{
       type  => syslog
       port  => 5544
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try the second method using rsyslog before choosing :-)